# How to develop app for Facebook Pages?

Tags: facebook, e-commerce, facebook-page

I want to develop a customized shopping cart. I have tried to install 2 shopping carts on my page.

1. VendorShop
2. Payvment E-Commerce

But these aren't serving my purpose. So i am thinking to develop my own. Could you give me a head start?

My most important question is, *is App development for **Facebook Pages** is different or its the same?*

A quick start guide?

Answer (score 0):

basically app dev for fb pages is pretty much the same as std fb app.
so, to get started, you can just refer to those community generated tutorials / start guide, or refer to fb docs.

I am sorry that I cannot provide the direct link here (as it seems to me that SO does not like it... I tried to do that before but my answer just get banned and down-graded from moderator).  If you want to get community generated tutorials, refer to my profile and you can get the link.